# Conditional Round If/then Statement - Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to target a specific percentage of sales mix.  For example 10% and 90% but from a practical standpoint I can't have partial sales.  I'd like to be able to have a conditional round where if the % time actual sales for a category rounding up exceeds the target % then it rounds down. If rounding up would stay below the threshold that would be good.

I've tried INT and Round but they don't address the conditional nature of this problem.  I.e sometimes rounding up makes sense and is below the threshold and others times it goes over.  Int just rounds down always so sometimes if the number of sales is small enough even though I should get one I end up getting 0.

Tried Round and Int with IF then's but nothing has materialized

I get the edge cases I mentioned.  Int with small numbers becomes 0 when it should be 1.  Round often exceeds the % target.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a sheet formula? Do you have any sample data, or the formulas you've entered? If this is VBA, please use the VBA tag.

Comment: Its a sheet formula.  No VBA. The formula I have is a mess right now but the basic need I have is:  say sales are 10 and the mix of customer 1 is 15% and customer 2 is 85%.  I want to be able to round down in this case because customer 1 can't have 2 sales and exceed 15%.  Conversely, if the sales were 5 and the customer were 10% it would round down is 10% of 5 rounded up would exceed the %.

Comment: Please post some example data (i.e., a what a spreadsheet would look like) with a few samples and your desired results, and we can help you :)

Comment: IF(ROUND(N38/N37,0)<N17,ROUND(N38,0),INT(N17))

Comment: N17 is 10.3%, N37 is 13 and N38 is 1.3

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57146210/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm following you but something like this?

```
  =IF(ROUNDUP(N38/N37,0)>N17,ROUNDDown(N38/N37,0),RoundUp(N38/N37,0))
```